# Vba Next Business Day Including holiday

Tags: vba, date

I want to have a function to return the next business day of the date that is sent in as parameter. 
Weekends and Canadian holidays should be included.
What is the easiest way to do this ? Is it possible to do this without setting a reference to a range of cells for the holidays' dates?

Comment: Nope, Excel doesn't know every holiday in every corner of the world - you have to supply it.

Comment: Whose holidays? US, UK, CANADA. if the US which state?  I hope the point is being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you provide a list of holidays, you won't be able to calculate the next working date. Remember the rules for Easter involve the phase of the moon! So this is not a simple task.

That is before you start to consider which different countries. Even if you restrict yourself to the US holidays, it takes a fair bit of calculations just to get the 3rd Thursday in November etc

Here is a demonstration of how you could calculate the next working day. 
I wouldn't hold just the holidays but every date in the calendar. Note for Easter I have fudged the holiday column to get the correct next working day answer.

You could miss a few steps in the calculation, I left them in for clarity.

[image: Excel demo]

Answer (score 0):

Use the =WORKDAY() function. You'll have to specify a range of holidays as the third parameter.